# Text fiting inside element issue in css

Tags: css, text, positioning

How can I make text inside `.inside-ob-u` which appers after hovering `.ob-nth2` not to do 'fitting process' as shown :

As is possible to clearly see the text is fitting when the height and width change is in the process.

How can I do it **without** absolute position or disabling transition? Works well if I do so.

https://jsfiddle.net/daf7a509/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `transform: scale(x)`. The nice thing is that `scale` doesn't change the space taken up by the element -> the other `elements` **don't move**.

https://jsfiddle.net/am7m384d/

**EDIT:**

> [...] but it also affects the content (childs) and mess things up. – user3734782

You could set the size of `.box__hover` to the size it should have when being hovered and `scale` it down when it is not hovered (for the `transition`). Then the children would have their correct size.

Here is an adapted fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b7w40gtp/

Comment: Nice answer, but it also affects the content (childs) and mess things up.

Comment: @user3734782 I didn't consider that. I have supplied an updated fiddle to remedy that.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of `.inside-ob-u` instead of using a percentage, it won't reflow. See https://jsfiddle.net/daf7a509/1/

Comment: Thank for your answer, but in that case the inner area will not be responsive. Isn't there other way? like to set text delay of transition duration or somthing like this?